# how to add javascript in wordpress template?

Tags: wordpress

I want to add 2 js files in my wordpress template function-dir.php.

how to add this js file is there any tag?

is it right function to use

```
wp_register_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );
```

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

You use wp_register_script to register a script with its handle in order to avoid duplicating code (if for instance you enqueue it in several places and need to update the filename). This is usually not needed, I usually use wp_enqueue_script(), which takes the same arguments and outputs it to the page.

I usually do this by creating a setup function with all my style and script enqueues and then hooking that function up to one of the pre-made hooks, like this:

```
function theme_enqueue() {
  /**
   * Scripts.
   */
  wp_enqueue_script('scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lib/scripts.pkgd.min.js', array('jquery'), THEME_VERSION);
  wp_enqueue_script('myscript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/myscript.js', array('scripts'), THEME_VERSION, TRUE);
  wp_enqueue_script('main-menu', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/menu.js', array('jquery'), THEME_VERSION, TRUE);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','theme_enqueue');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following structure as plugin by using [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script);

```
function add_custom_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script_name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array(), '1.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_custom_js' );
```

If you are developing plugin, you can add this action to your plugin. Or you can put this to `functions.php`

Answer (score 0):

[wp_register_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) function is used to register your script once and call anywhere, anytime. And [wp_enqueue_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) is used to call it in your `functions.php` file

## Method: 1

```
// First Register
function register_my_scripts(){
    wp_register_script('handler_1', get_template_directory_uri() . "/js/script_one.js");
    wp_register_script('handler_2', get_template_directory_uri() . "/js/script_two.js");
}
add_action('init', 'register_my_scripts');
```

Now use :

```
function wp24_load_script() {
    // Check if you want to load for
    // specific page
    wp_enqueue_script('handler_1');
}
add_action("wp_enqueue_scirpts", "wp24_load_script");
```

### Method: 2

Or you can directly load it with wp_enqueue_script() function:

```
function wp24_load_script() {
    // Check if you want to load for
    // specific page
    wp_enqueue_script('handler_1', get_template_directory_uri() . "/js/script_one.js");
}
add_action("wp_enqueue_scirpts", "wp24_load_script");
```